# error large bars and toolbars in eclipse?

Tags: unity, eclipse, gtk, numix

this is my eclipse 4.2 GUI, in Numix theme:
[image: screenshot]

and in Ambiance theme(default)
[image: screenshot]
As title, Tabs and tool bars of my Eclipse too large. so, how do i fix it?
please don't tell me change to default theme, because i like it

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wait when a theme update will come out from Numix. I am having a similar problem with the Ambiance Aqua theme: can't enable overlay scrollbars. However the theme in eclipse mars 2.0 works just fine.